# Python Merge By Lowest Value Relative to Column

Tags: python, merge, minimum

My df:

```
df_val
0.1
0.3
0.4
0.7
```

The dataset with clusters to join is:

```
cl_val cluster
0.2       A
0.5       B
0.8       C
```

I want to join the clusters, such that for each row in df, it matches to the cluster that the df_val is below. Ie for the first row (0.1) the smallest cl_val it is less than 0.2 so cluster A. For row 2 (0.3) the smallest cluster val it is less than is 0.5, so cluster B. So for example the end result i want is:

```
df_val cluster
0.1       A
0.3       B
0.4       B
0.7       C
```

Any ideas how this can be done in Python? Perhaps using sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**Setup**

```
df_vals = pd.DataFrame({'df_val': [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7]})
clusters = pd.DataFrame({'cl_val': [0.2, 0.5, 0.8], 'cluster': ['A','B','C']})
```

**Merge**

```
merge_df = pd.merge_asof(df_vals, clusters, left_on='df_val', right_on='cl_val', direction='forward')
merge_df[['df_val', 'cluster']]
```

**Output**

```
    df_val  cluster
0   0.1     A
1   0.3     B
2   0.4     B
3   0.7     C
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe it was this easy. I've been running a if else code on a row by row basis....it has been running for the past 30 mins. The merge you suggested ran in 10 seconds and gives the results exactly as expected. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Another attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'df_val':[0.1, 0.3,0.4,0.7]})
dc = pd.DataFrame({'cl_val':[0.2,0.5,0.8], 'cluster':['A','B','C']})

df['cluster']  = df['df_val'].apply(lambda x: dc.iloc[(dc['cl_val'] > x).idxmax()]['cluster'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   df_val cluster
0     0.1       A
1     0.3       B
2     0.4       B
3     0.7       C
```